# How to add a JS library to an R package in R?

Tags: javascript, r

I am currently using the R package svg-pan-zoom in my R/shiny app : https://github.com/bumbu/svg-pan-zoom.
It would be very useful for to be able to rotate my svg image, which is not possible with the original package. Somebody developed a JS library that allows the rotation of the image, based on svg-pan-zoom : https://github.com/bastienmoulia/svg-pan-zoom-rotate
But how can I add this JS library in the R package I'm using?

On the Git page of svg-pan-zoom, I found the info below :
An example of how to load library using Require.js is available in demo/require.html
But the link "demo/require.html" leads to error 404.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: https://bumbu.me/svg-pan-zoom/demo/require.html ( https://github.com/bumbu/svg-pan-zoom/blob/master/demo/require.html )

Comment: See the vignettes of the **htmlwidgets** package.